# Is it possible to optimize this Oracle SQL query any further (EXISTS)?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, correlated-subquery

Hi hoping to have help to optimize the query below, it is taking 4+ hours to run when comparing two larger tables with 55k and 1.6M rows respectively.

I have 2 tables Oppty and Acc and a query to derive the "CF" field **(fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/sRT7-kvz)**

[Both tables here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snO5h.png)

And below have a query deriving where if there is **NO** match in Account_ID between the tables it will say **'No Match @ ACC_ID Level'**

1. If there **IS** a match at the ACC_ID level then, it will look at Prod1 match (anywhere in that ACC_ID), if **NO** Prod1 match it will just say **'Match @ ACC_ID Level'**
2. If there **IS** a match at the ACC_ID and Prod1 level then it will look at Prod2 match (anywhere in that ACC_ID) and if **NO** is Prod2 match it will say **'Match @ ACC_ID, Prod1 Levels'**, and if there **IS** a Prod2 match it will say **'Match @ ALL Levels'**

```
SELECT  
  op."Acc_ID"
, op."Oppty_ID"
, op."Prod1op"
, op."Prod2op"
, CASE WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM Acc ac 
            WHERE ac."Acc_ID" = op."Acc_ID") 
                  THEN 
                      CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                      SELECT 1 
                      FROM Acc ac 
                      WHERE ac."Acc_ID" = op."Acc_ID"
                      AND ac."Prod1acc" = op."Prod1op") 
                          THEN 
                              CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                              SELECT 1 
                              FROM Acc ac 
                              WHERE ac."Acc_ID" = op."Acc_ID"
                              AND ac."Prod1acc" = op."Prod1op"
                              AND ac."Prod2acc" = op."Prod2op") 
                                  THEN 'Match @ ALL Levels' 
                          ELSE 'Match @ ACC_ID, Prod1 Levels' END
                  ELSE 'Match @ ACC_ID Level' END
       ELSE 'No Match @ ACC_ID Level' END CF
FROM Oppty op
  ORDER BY op."Acc_ID", op."Prod1op"
```

[Output table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acZRe.png)

Comment: What's your oracle version?

Comment: Oracle database 19c enterprise edition release 19.0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You have three, count'em, three nested [correlated subqueries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery). It's almost certain that your execution plan ends up running each one for each outer query.

Refactor those correlated subqueries to LEFT JOINs and you'll recover some performance.

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT
  op."Acc_ID"
, op."Oppty_ID"
, op."Prod1op"
, op."Prod2op"
, CASE WHEN ac1."Acc_ID" IS NOT NULL AND  ac2."Acc_ID" IS NOT NULL AND ac3."Acc_ID" IS NOT NULL
       THEN  'Match @ ALL Levels'
       WHEN ac1."Acc_ID" IS NOT NULL AND  ac2."Acc_ID" IS NOT NULL 
       THEN  'Match @ ACC_ID, Prod1 Levels'
       WHEN ac1."Acc_ID" IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'Match @ ACC_ID Level'
       ELSE 'No Match @ ACC_ID Level' END CF       
FROM Oppty op
LEFT JOIN Acc ac1 ON op."Acc_ID" = ac1."Acc_ID"
LEFT JOIN Acc ac2 ON op."Acc_ID" = ac2."Acc_ID"
                   AND ac2."Prod1acc" = op."Prod1op"
LEFT JOIN Acc ac3   ON op."Acc_ID" = ac3."Acc_ID"
                   AND ac3."Prod1acc" = op."Prod1op"
                   AND ac3."Prod2acc" = op."Prod2op" 
  ORDER BY op."Acc_ID", op."Prod1op"
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hthySBw-).

Answer (score 0):

1 option is to rewrite it as lateral, so you would have just one lookup to `Acc` per row from `Oppty`:

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/gP5yyeoS

```sql
SELECT  
  op."Acc_ID"
, op."Oppty_ID"
, op."Prod1op"
, op."Prod2op"
, L.*
FROM Oppty op
     cross apply (
        SELECT
           case max(
                   case 
                     when ac."Prod1acc" = op."Prod1op" AND ac."Prod2acc" = op."Prod2op" then 3
                     when ac."Prod1acc" = op."Prod1op"                                  then 2
                     else 1
                   end)
                when 3 then 'Match @ ALL Levels' 
                when 2 then 'Match @ ACC_ID, Prod1 Levels'
                when 1 then 'Match @ ACC_ID Level'
                else 'No Match @ ACC_ID Level'
           end as CF
        FROM Acc ac 
        WHERE ac."Acc_ID" = op."Acc_ID"
     ) L
  ORDER BY op."Acc_ID", op."Prod1op"
```

Another variant is to join all rows and then reduce them to only max suited rows:

DBFiddle 2: https://dbfiddle.uk/1iSSy2Hr

See latest one there.

```sql
SELECT  
    op."Acc_ID"
  , op."Oppty_ID"
  , op."Prod1op"
  , op."Prod2op"
  , case
      max(
        case
             when ac."Acc_ID" = op."Acc_ID"
              AND ac."Prod1acc" = op."Prod1op"
              AND ac."Prod2acc" = op."Prod2op"
             then 3
             when ac."Acc_ID" = op."Acc_ID"
              AND ac."Prod1acc" = op."Prod1op"
             then 2
             when ac."Acc_ID" = op."Acc_ID"
             then 1
             else 0
         end
        )
      when 3 then 'Match @ ALL Levels' 
      when 2 then 'Match @ ACC_ID, Prod1 Levels'
      when 1 then 'Match @ ACC_ID Level'
      else 'No Match @ ACC_ID Level'
    end  as SF
FROM Oppty op
     left join Acc ac 
          on ac."Acc_ID" = op."Acc_ID"
group by 
    op."Acc_ID"
  , op."Oppty_ID"
  , op."Prod1op"
  , op."Prod2op"
  , op.rowid
ORDER BY op."Acc_ID", op."Prod1op"
```

In this case you can get simple Hash Join Right Outer with a very fast group-by.

You can also aggregate `Acc` to get just one row with all tuples of `Prod1acc`/`Prod2acc`, it should be even faster, but probably these 2 variants should be enough.

Just in case 3rd variant using collections (collections are not fast, usually it's better to aggregate to varchar2, but such approaches have length limits, so I wouldn't advice it here, since I don't know your details about your data):

DBFiddle 3: https://dbfiddle.uk/yoZfReji

```sql
with 
acc_agg as (
   select
      ac."Acc_ID"
     ,cast(collect(sys.ku$_ObjNumNam(1,ac."Prod1acc")) as sys.ku$_ObjNumNamSet) tuples_1
     ,cast(collect(sys.ku$_parsed_item(ac."Prod1acc",ac."Prod2acc",0)) as sys.ku$_parsed_items) tuples_2
   from acc ac
   group by ac."Acc_ID"
)
SELECT  
  op."Acc_ID"
, op."Oppty_ID"
, op."Prod1op"
, op."Prod2op"
, case 
     when aa."Acc_ID" = op."Acc_ID" 
       then 
         case 
            when sys.ku$_parsed_item(op."Prod1op",op."Prod2op",0) member of aa.tuples_2 
              then 'Match @ ALL Levels' 
            when sys.ku$_ObjNumNam(1,op."Prod1op") member of aa.tuples_1
              then 'Match @ ACC_ID, Prod1 Levels'
            else 'Match @ ACC_ID Level'
         end
     else 'No Match @ ACC_ID Level'
  end as SF
FROM Oppty op
     left join acc_agg aa
          on aa."Acc_ID" = op."Acc_ID"
ORDER BY op."Acc_ID", op."Prod1op";
```

Comment: Hi between option 1 and 2 which one do you think is faster? In addition, is your option 2 similar to O. Jones solution?

Comment: @Noobanalyst415 2nd should be faster on your tables, but it would be easier to test for you. And - no, both of them are different from his solution